# Trouble adding dll file to visual studio in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, alglib

I'm new to coding in C#, and I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. My problem is that when I'm adding a reference from a dll file, it's highlighting in red the import "using alglibnet2;" I am trying to add a reference to my code from Alglib to calculate the covariance matrix covm(). I did put the dll file in a lib folder with my code too. Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Also make sure that the alglibnet2 dll is of a compatible version.  That is, is it a full .NET DLL and you're compiling for Silverlight (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 9):

You need to right click on the project and choose *Add Reference*, then navigate to the location of the assembly.

Comment: @MichaelLoftus Also, after you've added the reference as Gabe described right click on it, choose properties, confirm the path is correct, copy local is set to true.

Comment: I actually did add the reference by right-clicking on the project, and it did not work still. Maybe my dll file is not compatible?

Comment: Do you see the reference in the list of references after doing so?

Comment: I fixed it, I had to type alglib.covm(matrix1.ToArray(), out covarianceMatrix); instead of doing "using alglib."